# parameter 12 of function XMLFOREST must be aliased

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am new to creating custom XML using complex oracle sql queries, so I get the above error anytime i try running this code . I intend generating the custom xml below from the values gotten from the database and also hard-code some strings for values not available in the table.

```
SELECT XMLAGG(
    XMLElement(
        "transaction", 
        XMLForest(
            T_TRANS_NUMBER transactionnumber,
            T_TRANS_NUMBER internal_ref_number,
            T_LOCATION transaction_location,
            TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION transaction_description,
            T_DATE date_transaction,
            T_TELLER teller,
            T_AUTHORIZED authorized,
            T_LATE_DEPOSIT late_deposit,
            T_VALUE_DATE value_date,
            T_TRANSMODE_CODE transmode_code,
            T_AMOUNT_LOCAL amount_local,
            XMLElement(
                "t_from",
                XMLForest(
                    T_SOURCE_FUNDS_CODE from_funds_code,
                    XMLElement(
                        "from_account",
                        XMLForest(
                            T_SOURCE_INSTITUTION_NAME institution_name,
                            T_SOURCE_INSTITUTION_CODE institution_code,
                            'false' non_bank_institution,
                            T_SOURCE_ACCOUNT_NUMBER account,
                            T_SOURCE_CURRENCY_CODE currency_code,
                            T_SOURCE_ACCOUNT_NAME account_name
                        ) as "CCC" 
                    ),
                    T_SOURCE_COUNTRY from_country
                ) as "BBB"
            )
        ) as "AAA" 
    )
) AS "RES"
   FROM TRANSACTION_DROPPED;
```

I am trying to get the structure below

```
<transaction>
    <transactionnumber>***</transactionnumber>
    <internal_ref_number>***</internal_ref_number>
    <transaction_location>***</transaction_location>
    <transaction_description>***</transaction_description>
    <date_transaction>***</date_transaction>
    <teller>***</teller>
    <authorized>***</authorized>
    <late_deposit>***</late_deposit>
    <value_date>***</value_date>
    <transmode_code>***</transmode_code>
    <amount_local>***</amount_local>
    <t_from>
        <from_funds_code>***</from_funds_code>
        <from_account>
            <institution_name>***</institution_name>
            <institution_code>***</institution_code>
            <non_bank_institution>***</non_bank_institution>
            <account>***</account>
            <currency_code>***</currency_code>
            <account_name>***</account_name>
        </from_account>
        <from_country>***</from_country>
    </t_from>
</transaction>
```

This task has bugged me for so long so i will appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer I needed to aliase the XMLElement within the XMLForest. See Updated query below. The downside is that it add an extra tag which is the same name as the aliase provide, which I don't want.

```
SELECT XMLAGG(
    XMLElement(
        "transaction", 
        XMLForest(
            T_TRANS_NUMBER transactionnumber,
            T_TRANS_NUMBER internal_ref_number,
            T_LOCATION transaction_location,
            TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION transaction_description,
            T_DATE date_transaction,
            T_TELLER teller,
            T_AUTHORIZED authorized,
            T_LATE_DEPOSIT late_deposit,
            T_VALUE_DATE value_date,
            T_TRANSMODE_CODE transmode_code,
            T_AMOUNT_LOCAL amount_local,
            XMLElement(
                "t_from",
                XMLForest(
                    T_SOURCE_FUNDS_CODE from_funds_code,
                    XMLElement(
                        "from_account",
                        XMLForest(
                            T_SOURCE_INSTITUTION_NAME institution_name,
                            T_SOURCE_INSTITUTION_CODE institution_code,
                            'false' non_bank_institution,
                            T_SOURCE_ACCOUNT_NUMBER account,
                            T_SOURCE_CURRENCY_CODE currency_code,
                            T_SOURCE_ACCOUNT_NAME account_name
                        ) 
                    ) as "MAX2",
                    T_SOURCE_COUNTRY from_country
                ) as "BBB"
            ) as "MAX1"
        ) as "AAA" 
    )
) AS RES
   FROM TRANSACTION_DROPPED;
```